# LiDAR data download, merge and mosaic (Minnesota state)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, merge, lidar, mosaic

I have been using the toolbox found [here](http://www.mngeo.state.mn.us/chouse/elevation/lidar.html) to download LiDAR data for MN (Minnesota-US).

The tool is very convenient for downloading multiple tiles but the merge/mosaic function of the tool is failing. The result is all the tiles are stored individually in separate gdb's which makes it very time consuming to extract in order to mosaic them on my own.

1. Is the merge/mosaic function of the tool failing because the tool is designed for 10.1 and I'm using 10.2? Anyone else have this problem or a solution?
2. Is there a way to combine/extract all of these tiles from multiple gdb's into one gdb in order to mosaic all the tiles?

Comment: Welcome to the GIS SE Nick.  Are you merging the raw .laz tiles or the DEM data?  One work-around is to download the tiles using MNTOPO.

Comment: Hi Aaron. I'm merging the DEM data. I'm giving the MNTOPO suggestion a try at the moment and will share how that works out. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: You will need to use either Python or ModelBuilder to automate this process--are you open to MB or Python solutions?

Comment: I'm more familiar with MB then Python so i'd love to hear.

Comment: The MNTOPO download viewer outputted the merged DEM tiles successfully. The only draw back to this approach is free-handing the large irregular polygon for my extent but I'm not complaining. I am still curious about the MB method though. Thank's again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ModelBuilder for this task.  In this example, the submodel is used to iterate through multiple workspaces to find and list all of the DEMs.  Make sure to select the recursive iterator option and set a wildcard if necessary.  The full model takes the list of DEMs and mosaics them.

**Submodel "collectValues"**

[image]

**The recursive iterator**

[image]

**Full model**

[image]